# SQL open failure leads to systematic TransactionAbortedException (due to timeout) until application pool is recycled

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database

We have a Worker Role that is hosted in Azure and uses SQL Azure for its database. Occasionally, there will be an SQL connection error: `System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)`

Once this error has occurred, all following attempts to create a connection/transaction will fail with the following error: `System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.TimeoutException: Transaction Timeout` essentially rendering our entire service unusable (since all of our services require database access).

The only solution we've found is to manually recycle the application pool. Obviously, this is causing issues since whenever this happens, our instance becomes unable to service requests until somebody manually recycles the application pool.

Obviously, we're looking for another solution, either a fix to the issue altogether or a workaround that we can put into place to automate the application pool recycle (or something that can achieve a similar result).

One thing to note, we are using Entity Framework 4 (old project, it works as-is and we've found no reason to upgrade yet). As such, since EF4 will open/close the database connection for each query or `SaveChanges` call, our code forces the connection to open when the transaction is created using `ObjectContext.Connection.Open()` to avoid having the transaction promoted to a MSDTC if there are multiple queries or updates within the same transaction. It is during this initial open that the exception occurs.

For the `TransactionScope` we are using `TransactionScopeOption.Required` and `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found!

The issue is that we were using an object `EFTransaction` to wrap both the `TransactionScope` as well as the `ObjectContext` in order to automate the creation of the scope and the opening of the connection. This code was found in the constructor of this type:

```
this._transactionScope = new TransactionScope(transactionScopeOption, transactionOptions);
this.OpenConnection();
```

While the class itself is `IDisposable`, the exception is happening within the constructor. As such, the reference to the object never gets assigned and the `Dispose()` never gets called. Therefore, the `_transactionScope` field never gets Disposed and the transaction is stuck in limbo, which causes following transaction requests to timeout.

The solution is two-fold: first, implement a finalizer on the class. While the time of finalization execution is undefined, it's still preferable to leaving a pending transaction in limbo. At least at some point the object will get GC'd and the transaction disposed and other transactions will resume.

Second, wrap `this.OpenConnection()` in a try/catch and `Dispose()` the transaction if the open fails:

```
this._transactionScope = new TransactionScope(transactionScopeOption, transactionOptions);
try
{
    this.OpenConnection();
}
catch
{
    this._transactionScope.Dispose();
    throw;
}
```

This handles the exception case and leaves no pending "zombie" transactions.